# I can't establish expo-cli

Tags: expo

Whenever I establish `exp0-cli` on npm, cmd gives an error. At the same time I try bash and powershell, but that gives the same error.

Error page:
[image]

What do I do for this problem?

Comment: try executing it with sudo

Comment: Yes I tried but wasn't work.